# Why does Azure AD B2C redirect with a code instead of id_token?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set up AD B2C and am following along with various tutorials I've found online. I'm at the point where I'm testing user flows. I can successfully login, but when I'm redirected to `https://jwt.ms`, it shows me nothing:

[image]

However, I noticed that my URL differs from that shown in tutorials. It has a `code` instead of `id_token`:

```
https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraW...
```

I've been trying to figure out what is causing B2C to redirect with a code rather than ID token, but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me why this might be occurring?

**UPDATE**

OK, I see what's causing this now, but don't really understand where my setup differs from what I'm seeing in tutorials. I found that if I enable implicit grants on my app registration as follows:

[image: Grants]

Then everything works as expected. Note that I have to enable *both*.

I also noticed that when I test a user flow, the status of those implicit grants determines whether it has `response_type=code` or `response_type=id_token` in the authorization URL:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a way to set the desired `response_type` from within the test user flow UI other than changing the status of the implicit grants. Maybe this is a change of behavior in the Azure portal since the tutorials were made...?

Comment: What does your authorization request URL look like?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I added some updates to my Q

Comment: It’s always been like this.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, if we set **Implicit grant** in Azure AD app, the user flow endpoint will generate `response_type=id_token` instead of `response_type=code`. It is by-design of Azure AD B2C user flow.

If we don't do this, `response_type=code` means it is [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow)， that is why you get this: `https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraW...`.

I'm not sure why you want to change the response_type in other ways. It should be the easiest. But if you want to change it manually, just click the copy button, change the response_type value, and then access it in the browser.

[image]