# Azure B2C authorization code is not returned as expected

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up Azure B2C for my application. It has both a backend, and a SPA style frontend, and am looking to use both for some of the auth work I have to do. This means that I need to enable both of them to suit my workflow.

[image: Grants]

But the issue with this is that, on web apps the redirect URIs (shown below) are sent as `https://localhost.com/account#id_token=xxxxxx` when I expect them to be `https://localhost.com/account?code=xxxxxx` for webapps!

[image]

B2C differentiates b/w WebApps (server tech) and SPA apps (as shown below), so I expect B2C to serve the appropriate token types (the `#` type for SPA, and the `?` query type for webapp). Instead, I get the `#id_token=xxxx` for the webapp when `Access Tokens` is enabled in the `Implicit Grant` options above. Why is this the case?

I currently got around the issue by disabling `Access Tokens` in the `Implicit Grant`. What am I misunderstanding here?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62226700/8560442), but doesn't answer my question as to why B2C is using the wrong token type.

[image]

Comment: Is your app requesting an authorization code?

Comment: I'm just running the auth flow from 'Run this user flow' from the B2C dashboard

Answer (score 0):

When you use “run now”, we detect if implicit flow is enabled and use it by default. It’s useful since you can then see the token straight away.

When you use your app code, the response_type will be we to code, so it will respond with the auth code. Or otherwise disable implicit flow on the App Registration if you want to test your apps reply url with auth code as the response mode. Or just edit the Run Now url manually.